# XSD Sequence of Choice

Tags: xml, xsd, sequence

I want to write a schema which accept XML documents like this:

```
<plugin>
  <label text="blabla" />
  <line />
  <break />
  <textbox name="mytextbox" length="8" required="true" />
  <checkbox name="mycheckbox" checked="true" />
  <combobox name="mycombo">
    <option value="one">Option One</option>
    <option value="two" selected="true">Option One</option>
  </combobox>
  <break />
</plugin>
```

So I want the plugin to contain elements of set {combobox,checkbox,textbox,label,line,break}. 
I have written this XSD, but this is wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="plugin">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="line" />
        <xs:element name="break" />
        <xs:element name="label">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="bold" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="textbox">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
            <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
            <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:boolean" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="combobox">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="option" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="option_Text" msdata:Ordinal="2">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:attribute name="selected" type="xs:boolean" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="checkbox">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="checked" type="xs:boolean" />
            <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
       </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="plugin" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I have tested it with [this validator tool](http://tools.decisionsoft.com/schemaValidate/)...

but it says:

> "cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'line'. No child element is expected at this point."

So...What's wrong? I don't understand this message. What child elements at what point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `sequence` definition only has one child, i.e. `choice`.

This means that `plugin` is only permitted one child, though it may be any one of the elements you have defined.

If you remove the `choice` element, leaving its content in situ, you will have a fixed sequence of elements that can be children of `plugin`.

If, instead, you remove the sequence element, leaving it's content in situ, *and* add an attribute to the `choice` element: `maxOccurs="unbounded"`, then it should validate a `plugin` element with any number of the children you specify, in any order.

Comment: Actually, I've just seen that it's not quite this simple, hold on, I'll improve the answer.

Comment: I used the "sequence of choices" pattern because I thought it would be right, because plugin has a sequence, while the elements of the sequence could be textbox, combobox, etc.

Comment: Sequence of choices is essentially correct, but you do need to add that maxOccurs to keep selecting the choice again.

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to repeat the choice over and over in your sequence:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
```